# Why does `DataFrame.as_matrix` convert to float type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame and want to convert it to an array. Below is my code:

```
>>> test.columns
Index(['OverallQual', 'GrLivArea', 'GarageCars', 'TotalBsmtSF', 'FullBath',
       'YearBuilt'],
      dtype='object')
>>> test.head()
   OverallQual  GrLivArea  GarageCars  TotalBsmtSF  FullBath  YearBuilt
0            5        896         1.0        882.0         1       1961
1            6       1329         1.0       1329.0         1       1958
2            5       1629         2.0        928.0         2       1997
3            6       1604         2.0        926.0         2       1998
4            8       1280         2.0       1280.0         2       1992

>>> test.as_matrix()
array([[  5.00000000e+00,   8.96000000e+02,   1.00000000e+00,
          8.82000000e+02,   1.00000000e+00,   1.96100000e+03],
       [  6.00000000e+00,   1.32900000e+03,   1.00000000e+00,
          1.32900000e+03,   1.00000000e+00,   1.95800000e+03],
       [  5.00000000e+00,   1.62900000e+03,   2.00000000e+00,
          9.28000000e+02,   2.00000000e+00,   1.99700000e+03],
       ..., 
       [  5.00000000e+00,   1.22400000e+03,   2.00000000e+00,
          1.22400000e+03,   1.00000000e+00,   1.96000000e+03],
       [  5.00000000e+00,   9.70000000e+02,   0.00000000e+00,
          9.12000000e+02,   1.00000000e+00,   1.99200000e+03],
       [  7.00000000e+00,   2.00000000e+03,   3.00000000e+00,
          9.96000000e+02,   2.00000000e+00,   1.99300000e+03]])
```

From above output you can see that the values returned from `test.as_matrix()` are float values. I wonder why it converts everything to float even they are not.

Comment: At last one column has a float type, so all other columns will also be converted to float: the matrix (2D array, really) can only have one `dtype`, so it picks the "lowest common denominator" that can capture all values. E.g., converting everything to `int` would lose precision (disregarding the `.0` for every float value in the columns, since it would be a human interpretation to see those values as ints).

Comment: you could instead do `test.astype(object).values`

Comment: Thanks `test.astype` works

Comment: Why do you need to convert to an array?  I ask because the solutions available to you may differ based on what the array is used for.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I want to perform ML algorithm like Linear Regression. So I can use array to do some maths calculations like: `y = a + bx` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that the documentation says `DataFrame.as_matrix()` should no longer be used, and instead you should use `DataFrame.values`.

Second, note that your original data appears to have `dtype=object`.  This is not efficient!  You should load your original data with `dtype=int` if it is integer data.  Then, when you call `DataFrame.values`, the dtype will already be int.

Using `dtype=object` is not efficient because it stores the values elsewhere, with pointers to the values stored inside the DataFrame.  This can increase memory consumption by 100%, and decrease performance.